# Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: dual-boot

I have 300 GB hard-drive and I already installed Windows 7 on 35 GB partition + 100 mb for its boot files

Now I want to partition my hard-drive for ubuntu
Is this table ok?

10 GB for /
60 GB for /home
3 GB for swap
256 MB for /boot
And rest for DATA partition to store my movies, pictures, music etc.

(I don't want much space for multimedia files on ubuntu partition since I'll be using shared partition for that files.)

Can you tell me how to achieve this? Which software should I use to partition my hard drive? Which partitions should be primary and which should be logical? Where should I install Grub?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use GParted from the Ubuntu Live CD for partitioning. Resize available partitions if necessary and create new partitions as you want. You can also do partitioning in installation process.
2. I suggest you to specifying more size for `/` partition.
3. Don't worry about primary and logical partition. Ubuntu can be installed on any partition.
4. If you choose any partition as `/boot` partition, Grub will be install on it.
   Bootloader of Ubuntu will be installed on MBR by default. Don't worry about Windows. Grub will detect it and will add it on boot menu.