# How to partition for dual-boot Linux/Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101980/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-11-10)

I just got a new laptop with Windows 7 Home Premium pre-installed and the 750GB HDD already partitioned three ways (OS, Data, Recovery). I'd like to completely re-partition with Ubuntu, Swap and one Windows partition, but I'm confused at to what is the best way to do this.

I've been told that Windows' bootloader always wants to reside in the MBR. Does this mean I **have** to install Windows *before* installing Ubuntu (meaning that Windows is the first partition on the HDD) or can it be done so that it's laid out in the order:

Ubuntu [500GB] > Swap [6GB] > Windows [whatever's left]

I know that if I install Windows after Ubuntu, GRUB will be removed from the MBR, but is it possible then to just re-install GRUB, or will Windows always resist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The, in my opinion, best way to reformat your drive is:
1)defrag the windows partition(not something i do unless i'm resizing a drive)
2)shrink it with windows tools to whatever size gives you enough space
3)leave the recovery partition alone in case you need to re-install for whatever reason
4)in the ubuntu installer create whatever free space - swap partition you need
5)done

It lets you do a windows re-install if you don't have the disk and it just works.

Windows doesn't HAVE to be on the first partition on the disk.  The install windows first thing you're hearing is that if you install windows second it will wipe out the MBR and you'll have to re-install grub.

Comment: The thing is, I'll likely re-install Windows anyway, as the version that came with it is a typical OEM crapware-laden Home Premium image. I have a copy of Windows 7 Professional that I can use instead. In that situation, would it be a good bet to go with Lakritsbollar's suggestions above?

Comment: Separating home is hit or miss if you have large version changes, but it is valid.  I don't think windows lets you specify your partitioning much, so you'll probably want to do all the partition setup from live media.  Then just choose the target partition to install to from windows media.

Comment: Windows can partition a hard drive just fine. See [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsveMWRdNxo) for instance (you can skip ahead to 1:30 or so).

Comment: @Lakritsbollar I see it.  I just remembered the custom options not letting me do something I was trying to do with partitioning.  It may have been a feature stripped version of 7 I was using.

Answer (score 1):

You can partition the drive that way if you want, and then install Windows, followed by Ubuntu. Start the Windows install, delete all partitions, and then add the partitions you mentioned -- but just install Windows to the final one. Windows should have no problems with this.

I would recommend getting a separate partition for `/home` so you can format and reinstall the Ubuntu system at any time (or choose some other Linux distro if you feel like it down the road) with the least amount of hassle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I had actually forgotten about having a separate `/home` partition - it was something I had originally planned to do. Cheers for the reminder!

In general, what kind of split are we looking at between `/` and `/home`? i.e. how much space should I ideally give to each? I know that's like asking the "how long is a piece of string" question, but thought I'd just throw it out there :)

Comment: Is this just your desktop system, or do you plan to run some kind of server on it? If it's just your own desktop, I think that you will be more than fine with something like 20GB for `/` and the rest for `/home`. A server that places a lot of stuff in `/var/` will of course need more space there. Given that you're dual-booting I'm guessing you're not going to use it as a server, though. :)

Comment: Nah, this is just for a laptop, so no need for `/var` partition. Cheers for the suggestions. It's always unnerving doing anything to a new computer for the first time. Better prepare a USB key with GParted and get started :)

Answer (score 0):

Dowload Gparted, burn it on CD. You will all find it here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Comment: Julien, you misunderstand the question. I know to go about partitioning, but I have never freshly partitioned with the intention of dual-booting, so I asked here to find out the best way.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer.  In that case you can always "repair" the MBR with boot-repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair